# how to add new Fields into solr schema

Tags: mongodb, solr, lucene

I am doing data import from Mongo to Solr. For this I need to add new fields into the Solr schema. I am using solr server 5.1.0.

1. Schema.xml is not available in solrhome/server/solr/core/config directory so I copied one from solr-5.1.0\server\solr\configsets\basic_configs\conf to core\config and added fields into this.
2. Now when we start Solr server I get WARN message that I should remove the schema.xml file as this is now managed-schema. These fields should be moved to managed-schema file, but this didn't happen.
3. How Solr will move the database table to indexing. Does it convert each row into a document? Or I have to specify document structure somewhere?
4. How I can re index the data previously imported?

Answer (score 0):

For Data import you need db-data-config.xml file where you will put your sql  queries and configure it with SOLR For information about how to achieve the configuration go to this [link](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler)

Comment: How i can add new fields into solr schema ? By now i could find one way that is by deleting the managed-schema file. copy edited schema.xml and restart the server ? is there any proper way of adding new fields to schema ?

Answer (score 0):

I have find a way to add the fields into schema. Please provide your input if there is any other proper way of doing it.
1. add schema.xml file into your solr/core1/conf directory.
2. copy all content of managed-schema into schema.xml
3. add the new fields into schema.xml.
4. delete the managed-schema.xml
5. restart the solr it will create a managed-schema.xml and will move schema.xml to scheam.bkp

References-

1. solrconfig.xml - Read the doc for schemaFactory tag.

Comment: If I add the new fields to the managed_schema.xml file everything works fine. Isn't it a good practice? If not, why?

Comment: I have added new fields on managed_schema but still show data fetched: 500, processed: 0.