# SolrJ solr query for boolean params getting undefined field exception

Tags: solr, solrj, solr4

Hi i am using a slorj api to query solr indexes. But i am getting some exception when i add following query to SolrQuery object.

When i run following query in browser it is working fine 
http://localhost:8983/solr/hellosolr/select?q=fkey:book+OR+bookstore+AND+whword:what&fl=fanswer
it is working fine but when i run the same query using SolrQuery i am getting following exception

```
SolrQuery solrQuery = new SolrQuery();
solrQuery.set("q", "fkey:book+OR+bookstore+AND+whword:what");
solrQuery.set("fl", "fanswer");
```

Exception-

```
org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at http://localhost:8983/solr/hellosolr: org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError: Cannot parse 'fkey:book+OR+bookstore+AND+whword:what': Encountered " ":" ": "" at line 1, column 39.
Was expecting one of:
    <EOF> 
    <AND> ...
    <OR> ...
    <NOT> ...
    "+" ...
```

Please tell me how i can write above html query using SolrQuery java api.

Answer (score 0):

Your error message is a syntax error. Take out the + signs.

For the exception, try this query instead:

`(fkey:book OR fkey:bookstore) AND whword:what`

or you can write it like this (note the parentheses):

`(fkey:book bookstore) AND whword:what`

If you have OR defined as your default, then Solr will insert it between book and bookstore for you. Otherwise it will do an AND. I believe OR is the default. Check your `solrconfig.xml` to be sure.

If you don't specify a field in front of a search term, Solr will use the default field (it's `text` in my version, for example). If Solr can't find it, you'll get the `undefined field [name]` error.

Now, *why* your bad query is working from the admin panel, I don't know, but this should solve your SolrJ problem.

Assuming you're using the `/select` handler, you can go to `solrconfig.xml` and change the default:

```
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
    <int name="rows">10</int>
    <str name="df">blah</str>
</lst>
```

Comment: this error was resolved when i set the query parser in SolrQuery object solrQuery.set("defType","dismax"); But i have some more queries, I am doing some poc on solr and for uploading document using xml file i havent created schema.xml and defined fields into that. Is it necessary for us to create schema.xml and define fields to index data into solr.?  Please check my another question on adding fields http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30775018/how-to-add-new-fields-into-solr-schema